Passing an Enum as a tool to a client: "TypeError: Object of type ModelMetaclass is not JSON serializable"
I'm attempting to call a tool in langchain.
The function takes an IntEnum input. It rolls a dice and returns a random integer.
import random
from enum import IntEnum

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.tools import Tool, tool
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

load_dotenv()


class Dice(IntEnum):
    """
    Roll a D&D dice. A d4 dice has 4 sides and thus
    rolling a d4 dice will return a value from 1 through 4.
    """

    d4 = 4
    d6 = 6
    d8 = 8
    d10 = 10
    d12 = 12
    d20 = 20
    d100 = 100


def roll_dice(dice: Dice) -> int:
    """
    Simulates rolling a dice with a specified number of sides.

    Parameters:
    dice (Dice): A dice to roll.

    Returns:
    int: The result of the dice roll.
    """
    return random.randint(1, dice.value)


class RollDiceInput(BaseModel):
    dice: Dice


def get_function_description(func):
    """Extract docstrings from the functions"""
    return func.__doc__.strip()


# Define the tool with the input schema
roll_dice_tool = Tool(
    name="roll_dice",
    description=get_function_description(roll_dice),
    args_schema=RollDiceInput,
    func=roll_dice,
)

# Define the prompt
prompt = """
Roll a dice in Dungeons and Dragons.
"""

client = AzureChatOpenAI()

# Call the GPT-4 API with descriptions extracted from docstrings
response = client.invoke(
    model="gpt-4o",
    input=prompt,
    tools=[roll_dice_tool],
    tool_choice={
        "type": "function",
        "function": {"name": "roll_dice"},
    },  # forces the model to call the `roll_dice` function
)

It yields the error:
TypeError: Object of type ModelMetaclass is not JSON serializable.
It seems to fail on serializing the function.
How do I correctly pass and define a tool for the roll_dice function?
langchain 0.3.0
langchain-openai 0.2.0

can you run the code in try-except block to see which block of code is causing issue?

You have to bind the tools to the llm model. This creates a runnable with that can call tools. Then invoke this object with the input prompt. Also, unlike client.chat.completions.create of the openai module, the model name must be passed in the chat model definition, not during the call to the API.
client = AzureChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4o")

client_with_tool = client.bind_tools(     # <--- bind the tool here
    tools=[roll_dice_tool],
    tool_choice={
        "type": "function",
        "function": {"name": "roll_dice"},
    },  # forces the model to call the `roll_dice` function
)
response = client_with_tool.invoke(       # <--- invoke the client with the bound tools
    input=prompt,
)

